# Need modrewrite of wildcard subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I am trying to add a "/login" to wildcard subdomains.

For example:

*.example.com would be redirected to *.example.com/login

but, i want certain subdomains not to be redirected, such as...

**help.example.com, m.example.com, etc.**

What is the best way to do this, and would this be done in .htaccess or in httpd.conf?

Thank you for your help.

Updated below:

Here is what I currently have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^m.example.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(.+).example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/$ https://%1/login [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Check the documentation for `RewriteCond` or `RedirectCond`

Comment: It can be done either in .htaccess or in httpd.conf, using either RewriteCond or RedirectCond.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^m\.example\.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^help\.example\.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(.+\.example\.com)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%1/login [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```